# Jquery retrieve width of specific div from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to retrieve the width of a div in an array of divs with jquery.  Normally I'd do something like this...

```
$("#divID").width()
```

Which would work fine, but I have to iterate through a list of divs this time, and this returns the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].width is not a function"

```
$("#parentID .childClass")[0].width()
$("#parentID .childClass")[1].width()
etc...
```

And using .width (as an attribute instead of a function) just returns "undefined".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT - apologies - I originally omitted the .childClass identifier which is what causes my jquery selection to correctly return a list of all divs.  My question is really simply how to return the width of one such div

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: What i see is that you used same id( `parentID`) for all divs.

Comment: Also $("#parentID")[0] isn't a jQuery object, use eq() if you want that

Comment: @d3wannabe, please take a look at my answer.

Comment: thanks all - never heard of eq() before but looks perfect - actually so does each() which I just hadn't thought of - I'm going to accept the answer shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `eq` in order to get a `div` at specified index .Here is an example:

**eq method reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.**

```js
var length=$('.parentClass').length;
for(i=0;i<length;i++){
   console.log($('.parentClass').eq(i).width());
}
```

```css
.parentClass{
   width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentClass"></div>
<div class="parentClass"></div>
```

Another solution is to use `each()`method.

```
$("#parentID .childClass").each(function(){
    //code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a jQuery plugin to do this. Just find child elements within a parent element and locate the nᵗʰ item.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.nthChild = function(childSelector, n) {
    return this.find(childSelector).eq(n);
  };
  $.fn.nthChildWidth = function(childSelector, n) {
    return this.nthChild(childSelector, n).width();
  };
})(jQuery);

console.log($('#parent-id').nthChildWidth('.child-class', 0));
console.log($('#parent-id').nthChildWidth('.child-class', 1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent-id">
  <div class="child-class" style="width:200px"></div>
  <div class="child-class" style="width:300px"></div>
</div>
```